# AWS Amplify - Unauthenticated users with APIService in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, amplifyjs

### Background

I'm working on a project that uses Amplify and Angular. I've created an API using Amplify where certain tables can be accessed by unauthenticated users (`{allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read]}`) and some require logging in.

---

### Problem

I'm getting this error when using the generated APIService in my component like this  `const response = await this.apiService.ListTodos()`:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No current user
```

---

### Question

How can I make this call using IAM when there's no logged in user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update Auth

```
amplify update auth
```

--> Enable unauthenticated users

Update Authorization Modes -> IAM

```
amplify update api
```

Update your Amplify.configure

```
 Amplify.configure({...awsExports,
  DataStore: { 
    authModeStrategyType: AuthModeStrategyType.MULTI_AUTH 
}});
```

Update schema for api in amplify folder

```
type Todo @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read] }]) { /** Model **/
```

The above authorization ONLY enabled unauthenticated users from accessing, to enable authenticated users, I added a similar rule

```
{allow: private, provider: iam or userPool, operations: [read, create, update]
```

Update the backend

```
amplify push
```

Reference your api from graphql query

```
import { API } from '@aws-amplify/api
import { listTodos } from './graphql/queries

let result = await API.graphql({ query: listTodos, authMode: 'AWS_IAM'});
```

To check authentication

```
let user = await Auth.currentUserSession()

if(!user){
 return false;
}

return true;
```

If youre using userPool instead of querying for unauthenticated users:

```
let result = await API.graphql({ query: listTodos, authMode: 'AWS_IAM'});
```

will be:

```
let result = null

if(!user) {
  result = await API.graphql({ query: listTodos, authMode: 'AWS_IAM'});
} 

result = await API.graphql({ query: listTodos});
```